# Handle date and time in ocaml

Tags: date, time, ocaml

Is there a way to handle date and time, some sort of module, in ocaml ? Vanilla ocaml i mean, so no OPAM, or this kind of things ?

It seems like there is nothing about it on the internet, i would have expected more docs for the OCaml langage, it's so frustrating...

I need it to do operations on date and time, transform date and times into seconds from epoch, and reverse it, ect...

If there is no way i will do my own functions, but if there is something already done in OCaml for that that would be way better !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OCaml Unix library provides the interface to standard POSIX date/time functions such as [time](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALtime), [mktime](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALmktime), [gmtime](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALgmtime), and [localtime](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALlocaltime). They should be sufficient for your task. See the standard [OCaml documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) for futher information.

Also, long time ago I wrote a [small library](https://github.com/ivg/date-time) that depends purely on the Unix module, and implements a few useful time transformations. I never published it, but feel free to grab the code, or use it as a set of examples.

And of course, there are plenty of libraries available in OPAM, or via a package manager of your operating system. It is always better, to reuse existing code, rather then duplicate it.

Comment: The [Calendar](http://calendar.forge.ocamlcore.org/) library is also widely used. I'd say it's a must if you want to do date/time handling.